# Retrieval of values in reverse order using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I understand working of *(p+i), but, what actually is happening at memory level when retrieving values with  *(p-i) or p[-i] through printf() function ?

```
 #include <stdio.h> 

int main() {    
    int i, arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, *p;
    p = &arr[4];    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)         
        printf("%d\t%d\t", *(p - i), p[-i]);    
    // why does this prints in reverse order?
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, `*(p - i)` and `p[-i]` are exactly the same with different syntax. It's interesting that you can also write, `-i[p]` with exactly the same meaning `*(p - i)`.

It prints in the reverse order because you start at `arr[4]` and then subtract `i` from the pointer, which subtracts `0`, `1`, `2` one by one until it reaches `4`, so it prints `p[4]`, `p[3]`, `p[2]`, `p[1]`, `p[0]` which is the array `arr` from the last element to the first.

Comment: thanks Iharob, I understand that already. But, What is actually going on at memory level, or in terms of bytes.

Comment: What do you mean? You don't understand pointer arithmetic?

Comment: ohhh!! thnks got it :p

Comment: sorry for foolish question!!

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned last element address in the pointer and subtracting address one by one and hence it prints in reverse order

Comment: Assume your integer takes 4bytes each, and let 1000 be the memory location of arr[0] then below are the memory allocation
1000=> arr[0]
1004=> arr[1]
1008=> arr[2]
1012=> arr[3]
1016=> arr[4]
Now when you allocated pointer to arr[4], it points to the location 1016...and now you decrease it one by one, which means decreasing 4 bytes at a time

Comment: got it man !! thnx

Comment: hi @ninja, please mark this answer useful by voting UP arrow if it was :-)